# 2010 13" MBP restarts self "due to problem" after RAM upgrade & software update

Tags: macbook-pro, error

My 13" 2010 MBP worked well up until I upgraded from 4GB memory to 8GB memory.  At this time, I also upgraded from 10.7 to 10.8.5 (I believe these are the correct versions, not completely sure).

After this, I noticed that things began to get pretty bad:

- MBP would restart itself randomly.
- MBP would freeze up when watching a video or other visually intensive things (such as using corners to switch between programs, or when maximizing a program, it would freeze right in the middle of the maximization, creating a weird looking warped window.)
- When frozen visually, the audio would still work.
- Occasionally, when frozen, if I held down the power button (playing chicken with it), and released it just before I expected it to shut down... suddenly the freeze would subside and MBP would come back to life.

More recently, sometimes when booting, I get on the grey startup screen a cascade of error log text (white font, black background).  Then the machine would boot as normal.

Freakin weird.

Here is a recent console log from after rebooting after "there was a problem":

```
Anonymous UUID:       CCDB26E7-C9FC-B1FB-E21E-6AE6D8C140F7

Sun Apr 19 09:37:15 2015
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff80160dcc1d): Kernel trap at 0xffffff80160a995c, type 14=page fault, registers:
CR0: 0x0000000080010033, CR2: 0xffffff800a184618, CR3: 0x0000000018ebe000, CR4: 0x0000000000000660
RAX: 0x0000000000600000, RBX: 0xffffff801e9babf0, RCX: 0x000000000000008e, RDX: 0xffffff80e229d028
RSP: 0xffffff8118863ae0, RBP: 0xffffff8118863af0, RSI: 0x0000000000002bfc, RDI: 0xffffff800a1845a0
R8:  0x0000000000000001, R9:  0x00000000cccccccd, R10: 0x0000000000000000, R11: 0xffffff8016030000
R12: 0xffffff801e971a38, R13: 0x0000000000000000, R14: 0xffffff80e2287000, R15: 0xffffff80166d0b80
RFL: 0x0000000000010046, RIP: 0xffffff80160a995c, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000010
Fault CR2: 0xffffff800a184618, Error code: 0x0000000000000000, Fault CPU: 0x0

Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff8118863770 : 0xffffff8016023139 
0xffffff81188637f0 : 0xffffff80160dcc1d 
0xffffff81188639c0 : 0xffffff80160f4486 
0xffffff81188639e0 : 0xffffff80160a995c 
0xffffff8118863af0 : 0xffffff80160a9ee1 
0xffffff8118863b60 : 0xffffff80164863f3 
0xffffff8118863c60 : 0xffffff80160e6193 
0xffffff8118863cc0 : 0xffffff7f98414add 
0xffffff8118863d00 : 0xffffff7f9841810f 
0xffffff8118863d20 : 0xffffff80164c564c 
0xffffff8118863d80 : 0xffffff80164e16e3 
0xffffff8118863dd0 : 0xffffff80164a51b5 
0xffffff8118863e40 : 0xffffff801649c67d 
0xffffff8118863eb0 : 0xffffff80164aad64 
0xffffff8118863ef0 : 0xffffff80164aae6f 
0xffffff8118863f30 : 0xffffff80164b06e2 
0xffffff8118863f80 : 0xffffff80164b0863 
0xffffff8118863fb0 : 0xffffff80160d7c67 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform(2.0)[BC44CC56-BEAC-30C0-9A5F-AE7D939EEF48]@0xffffff7f9840a000->0xffffff7f98462fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily(1.4)[045D5D6F-AD1E-36DB-A249-A346E2B48E54]@0xffffff7f969a9000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[2852ACFE-FD28-3C37-9B39-885201BB8D25]@0xffffff7f966c1000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task

Mac OS version:
13F34

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 13.4.0: Wed Dec 17 19:05:52 PST 2014; root:xnu-2422.115.10~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 45486BF2-BDDE-34CB-8C71-606FF3FE181B
Kernel slide:     0x0000000015e00000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8016000000
System model name: MacBookPro7,1 (Mac-F222BEC8)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 12317127534928
last loaded kext at 302562830331: com.apple.filesystems.msdosfs 1.9 (addr 0xffffff7f96fa6000, size 65536)
last unloaded kext at 510646357778: com.apple.driver.AppleMCP89RootPortPM   1.11 (addr 0xffffff7f97f19000, size 24576)
loaded kexts:
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetAdp  4.3.12
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetFlt  4.3.12
com.avast.AvastFileShield   2.1.0
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxUSB 4.3.12
com.avast.PacketForwarder   2.0
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxDrv 4.3.12
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.60
com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor  1.9.5d0
com.apple.driver.AGPM   100.14.34
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.2.7f4
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    124
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   2.6.3f4
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   2.6.3f4
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    2.0.4d1
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.0d1
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHWAccess  1
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight 170.4.11
com.apple.GeForceTesla  8.2.4
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 4.2.7f4
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   1.7.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.5.13
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.2.5
com.apple.driver.SMCMotionSensor    3.0.4d1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons  240.2
com.apple.driver.AppleIRController  325.7
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeLZVN 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache 35
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 240.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCardReader 3.4.1
com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient  3.6.7
com.apple.driver.XsanFilter 404
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.6.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub    683.4.0
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    3.8.1b2
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4331   700.20.22
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI    5.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  3.0.5
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBEHCI   660.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBOHCI   656.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 217.92.1
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   153
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   217.92.1
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.6.22
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  10.0.7
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 2.6.3f4
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   1.9.7fc2
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    1.14
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   91.1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.2.7f4
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.12d1
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.0.4
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   4.2.7f4
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP    2.2.6
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 2.6.3f4
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 2.6.3f4
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 5.7.1d6
com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDANV50HalTesla   8.2.4
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.12d1
com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDAResmanTesla    8.2.4
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 240.10
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  660.4.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   3.6.7
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageClass   3.6.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIMultimediaCommandsDevice  3.6.7
com.apple.iokit.IOBDStorageFamily   1.7
com.apple.iokit.IODVDStorageFamily  1.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOCDStorageFamily   1.7.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   650.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite  656.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCISerialATAPI   2.6.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.6.7
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 660.4.2
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.0.3b4
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b5
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   640.36
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.2
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily    4.5.5
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.6.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 686.4.1
com.apple.driver.NVSMU  2.2.9
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  278.11.2
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  7
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 371.1
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 1.9
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  23
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
```

Any suggestions guys?

Comment: Lets do some trouble shooting. Disable/remove following: Avast app and virtualbox, then test again without those 2.

Comment: RAM usually does not go on/off from good to bad and back again.

Answer (score 1):

I would try the following:

1. Try booting in safe mode: Hold the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key immediately after you boot the machine.
2. If you can run safe mode smoothly, then the problem is probably stemming from a third party application. If you can't run safe mode smoothly, it probably is a hardware (or hardware compatibility) problem.
3. Run AHT (Apple Hardware Test) by holding <kbd>D</kbd> on startup. Do that at least twice.
4. Preform a [PRAM](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18761?locale=en_AP) reset.
5. Preform a [SMC](https://support.apple.com/en-il/HT201295) reset.